# How to use Heroicons v2 in headlessui

Tags: tailwind-css

Hi i try use Heroicons in Headlessui but I encountered this error،how can i fix that?

Uncaught Error: You're trying to import `@heroicons/react/solid/SelectorIcon` from Heroicons v1 but have installed Heroicons v2. Install `@heroicons/react@v1` to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: There are two ways to fix the error:

1. install `@heroicons/react@v1`:

   ```
   npm i @heroicons/react@v1
   ```
2. Use `react-icons` instead of `heroicons`:

   ```
   npm i react-icons
   ```